# how can i center 2 selctor list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

in short I want to center this select but text-align center; don't work

does anyone know what I have to insert inside the style tag?

this is my code

```html
<table border=1>

  <tr>

    <td> <input type="number" value=0 id="n1" oninput="test()" /> <br/><br/> </td>

    <td> </td>

    <td> <input type="text" value=0 id="result" readonly /><br><br> </td>

  </tr>

  <tr>

    <td>
      <select id="selector1">

        <option value="s">Seconds</option>
        <option value="m">Minutes</option>


      </select>
    </td>

    <td> <button onclick="myFunction()">Invert</button> </td>

    <td>
      <select id="selector2">

        <option value="s">Seconds</option>
        <option value="m">Minutes</option>

      </select>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSJxK.png)

Comment: text-align:center is working fine if applied to `td`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `#selector1` and to `#selector2`:

`disaply: flex; justifyContent: center`

Comment: where? add this?

Comment: #selector1{
disaply: flex; justify-content: center
}

Don't work in style tag

Comment: Try `justifyContent`